# Condition after computation in data table R

Tags: r, data.table

This question is about efficient use of data.table in R.

Suppose the following DataTable

```
DataTable <- data.table(Id = rep(1:10,5), Method = rep(c("M1","M2","M3","M4", "M5"), each = 10), Value = rnorm(100))
```

What I want to know is: for which Ids the maximum absolute difference in value between M1 and M3 is more than 2?

I thought about this code:

```
DataTable[,if( max(abs(.SD[Method == "M1", Value] - .SD[Method == "M3", Value] )) > 2) 1, by = "Id"]$Id
```

This gives the desired output, but it seems so unelegant and is also quite slow. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Instead of subsetting the column within `.SD`, you can directly subset the 'Value' based on the logical index `DataTable[, as.integer(max(abs((Value[Method == "M1"] - Value[Method == "M3"]))) > 2), by = Id]`

Comment: Thank you this is much faster, but it doesn't give the Ids straight away. 'DataTable[, if(max(abs((Value[Method == "M1"] - Value[Method == "M3"]))) > 2) 1, by = Id]$Id' does. Then there is still the ugly if in the j expression...

Comment: Here, the expression cannot be used in the `i` as there are multiple expressions.  Do we assume that both 'M1' and 'M3' elements have equal length for each 'Id'

Comment: Yes in this case we do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 possible approaches:

1) Like what akrun suggested with `Value[Method=="M1"]`

```
DataTable[, Id[any(abs(Value[Method=="M1"] - Value[Method=="M3"]) > 2)], by=.(Id)]$V1
```

2) Cast into a wide format (might be slower with large dataset)

```
dcast(DataTable, Id ~ Method, sum, value.var="Value")[, Id[abs(M1 - M3) > 2]]
```

data:

```
set.seed(0L)
DataTable <- data.table(Id = rep(1:10, 5), 
    Method = rep(c("M1","M2","M3","M4", "M5"), each = 10), 
    Value = rnorm(50))
```

Comment: Ok, I ll accept the solution, but I am a bit disappointed that there is no way to have conditions based on groups using some sort of 'by' for the i expression.